# how to clear the screen after exit vim

Tags: vim, xterm, terminfo

Sometimes vim will leave something, i.e. press any key to continue, on the terminal and is there any way to return to a clear terminal after exiting vim?
I am new to vim and please tell me exactly what I should do.

Sorry I did not express my idea clear enough the first time. What I actually want to ask is that is there a way to return to a clear terminal after typing :q in vim without further input of commands.
I am using VIM 7.4 in Ubuntu, terminal type is xterm.

Comment: vim normally shouldn't do that -- but even if it does, where's the harm?

Comment: Please specify what platform and what terminal you're using.

Comment: VIM 7.4 on Ubuntu, terminal type is xterm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to do more stuffs by editing your `.vimrc` file

Add this to your .vimrc

```
command Qc :call ClearAndExit()
function ClearAndExit()
    :!clear
    :q!
endfunction
```

use `:Qc`  to quit.... it will clear the screen as well

Comment: before that just `export  TERM=xterm`  on your terminal and try the samething

Comment: this is the link i got info. from   http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60499/how-to-set-the-bash-display-to-not-show-the-vim-text-after-exit

Comment: I have edited the answer with `.vimrc` changes as well

Comment: which one did you try? .vimrc or changing the TERM ?

Answer (score 13):

Add to your ~/.vimrc:

```
au VimLeave * :!clear
```

Answer (score 4):

I use an alias to clear on any exit method including `:q`, `:wqa`. (this is for my osx brewed binary, find your own vim binary with `which vim`)

```
# .zshrc
alias vim="/usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.0094/bin/vim && clear"
```

Comment: So simple, so powerful, yet so underappreciated :)

Comment: This solution sort of works, but isn't great because it prevents passing arguments to vim and `clear` doesn't actually clear the scrollback buffer unless the E3 capability is defined (and it isn't in bash on standard Ubuntu).

Comment: I agree, I found it lacking as well and have not found a solution i'm really happy with

Comment: I was 100% inspired by this Answer, but to address the comments on this Answer:

Add the following line with reason to your `.bashrc`:

`function vim { vim "$@" && clear; }`

This lets you pass arguments to `vim` but also clears the terminal screen after `vim` is quit in any way. I apologize if this doesn't apply to `zsh` or `xterm`!

Answer (score 2):

If Vim is compiled with support for switching xterm-screens, it can do this by default, if you set the `t_ti` and `t_te` (Vim usually figures out, to what values this needs to be set by itsself). The gory details are explained at  `:h xterm-screens` (pasted below)

> (From comp.editors, by Juergen Weigert, in reply to a question)
>
> :> Another question is that after exiting vim, the screen is left as
>   it :> was, i.e. the contents of the file I was viewing (editing) was
>   left on :> the screen. The output from my previous like "ls" were
>   lost, :> ie. no longer in the scrolling buffer. I know that there is a
>   way to :> restore the screen after exiting vim or other vi like
>   editors, :> I just don't know how. Helps are appreciated. Thanks. : :I
>   imagine someone else can answer this.  I assume though that vim and vi
>   do :the same thing as each other for a given xterm setup.
>
> They not necessarily do the same thing, as this may be a termcap vs.
>   terminfo problem.  You should be aware that there are two databases
>   for describing attributes of a particular type of terminal: termcap
>   and terminfo.  This can cause differences when the entries differ AND
>   when of the programs in question one uses terminfo and the other uses
>   termcap (also see +terminfo).
>
> In your particular problem, you are looking for the control sequences
>   ^[[?47h and ^[[?47l.  These switch between xterms alternate and main
>   screen buffer.  As a quick workaround a command sequence like
>           echo -n "^[[?47h"; vim ... ; echo -n "^[[?47l" may do what you want.  (My notation ^[ means the ESC character, further down you'll
>   see that the databases use \E instead).
>
> On startup, vim echoes the value of the termcap variable ti (terminfo:
>   smcup) to the terminal.  When exiting, it echoes te (terminfo: rmcup).
>   Thus these two variables are the correct place where the above
>   mentioned control sequences should go.
>
> Compare your xterm termcap entry (found in /etc/termcap) with your
>   xterm terminfo entry (retrieved with "infocmp -C xterm").  Both should
>   contain entries similar to:
>           :te=\E[2J\E[?47l\E8:ti=\E7\E[?47h:
>
> PS: If you find any difference, someone (your sysadmin?) should better
>   check
>       the complete termcap and terminfo database for consistency.
>
> NOTE 1: If you recompile Vim with FEAT_XTERM_SAVE defined in
>   feature.h, the builtin xterm will include the mentioned "te" and "ti"
>   entries.
>
> NOTE 2: If you want to disable the screen switching, and you don't
>   want to change your termcap, you can add these lines to your .vimrc:
>           :set t_ti= t_te=

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You most certainly can.

Use the UNIX command to clear the screen.
    `clear`

Comment: Or type Control-L at the shell prompt.

Comment: An FAQ ([Why doesn't the screen clear when I type control/L?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_form_feed)).

Comment: Sorry I did not express my idea clear enough. What I actually want to ask is that is there a way to return to a clear terminal after typing :q in vim without further input of commands.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want to have to use a different command to exit Vim (e.g. `:Qc` as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31619016)) by manoj, and the EntangledLoops' `.vimrc` [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51330580) didn't work for me.

Inspired by Plato's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40904828), I found a similar solution by putting the following function in `.bashrc`:

```
# Vim exits to clear terminal screen
function vim {
   /usr/bin/env vim "$@" && clear
}
```

Using only `vim` inside the function was problematic due to the function calling itself recursively and creating an infinite loop, but adding `/usr/bin/env` eliminates this issue, ignoring the function and executing the first `vim` in the `PATH`.